# sorting a list alphabetically with numerical counting

Tags: python-3.x

I currently am required to sort a list lexicographic order, where repeated words are counted and are sorted accordingly. The highest recurrences are first, with alphabetical sorting happens afterwards. I am using a file to collect the first word in each line and then sorting how often that word is repeated to be printed as what word is sorted where. for example if apple has the most repeats, it will appear at the front of the printed list as apple. Below is my attempt of sorting this out:

```
x = open("file.txt", "r")

li1 = []
for line in x:
    user = line.split()
    name = user[0]
li1.append(name)
li2 = [[y,li1.count(y)] for y in set(li1)]
print(li2)

x.close()
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean here: "lexicographic order, where repeated words are counted and are sorted accordingly".  Are the words to be sorted by frequency descending, then secondarily by lexicographical order?  What is the question that you need help with? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask